# Подбор php-фрэймворка под поставленную задачу

Tags: framework, php

Всем привет!

Пишу свой сайт, он разрастается и его сложность увеличивается всё больше и больше, что естественно меня не устраивает. Понимаю ,что нужно пользоваться фрэмворком, но не с одним из них никогда не работал. Задача состоит в том, что у меня кириллический домен и ссылки строятся тоже на русском языке (не знаю, как это по-другому правильно назвать). Пример:

> `сайт.рф/страница/2`

Я пробовал это реализовать в codeigniter, но там всё основано на классах, а их русским языком не назовёшь. Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли реализовать такую структуру сайта на codeigniter (уж очень он мне понравился), ну или посоветуйте другой фрэймворк.

Заранее благодарен. )

Comment: .рф, русские ссылки - фу!

Comment: uWeb это было глупо с вашей стороны

Comment: В любом фреймворке все основано на классах, а их нельзя называть русскими буквами. В принципе саму идею можно реализовать через mod_rewrite, но я не вижу смысла в этом ни какого. Да и выглядит это дико и не удобно. Попробуйте такую ссылку скопировать с адресной строки браузер Google Chrome к примеру, получите что-то вроде http://xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0/2 по вашему это круто?

Comment: Обоснованно, но задача такая стоит, не зависимо от того нравиться мне это или нет )
Домен другой не могу взять, т.к. мой кириллистический оч хороший и лучше не придумать )

Comment: Пишите свой фреймворк или используйте костыли с реврайтами.

Comment: > а их русским языком не назовёшь

Кто вам такое сказал?

    $ php -r 'class Сайт {}; var_dump(new Сайт());'
    object(Сайт)#1 (0) {
    }

PS Да, это вредный совет :) Но коль у автора основной домен кириллический, то, думаю, такому проекту уже хуже стать не может :)

Comment: Переводите `страница` -> `page` и где нибудь ставьте метку, что `страница` это `page` класс, например.

Comment: Ну можно попробовать конечно в том же самом Zend использовать систему роутинга. Честно не пытался никогда туда вбивать что-то на русском языке.

Comment: Мне вообще интересно в чьи светлые головы пришла идея использования национальных алфавитов в URL ?

Как, интересно, зайти на такой сайт с произвольного (например вообще чужого) браузера ?

Comment: Чисто в теории IDN были таки придуманы для внутренних сайтов государств. Я вот например понятия не имею как мне попасть на какой-нибудь арабский IDN )))) Да и нужно ли оно мне. Геморроя с IDN хватает, начнем хотя бы с почтовых серверов, я тут возился полгода назад, чтобы научить Exim4 понимать мыло типа info@домен.рф, а он оказывается и не умеет работать с IDN.

Comment: Ну ничего себе, докатились.

А скоро появится еще и, кто помнит конечно паскаль на русском, пользовались? Жесть не правда ли? А тут домен РФ и ссылки на кирилице, мдям, наверное вы просто не так поняли что домен рф никак не связан с тем что у него просто обязаны быть кириллические адреса.

ИМХО это бред. Начальнику скажите что он тупой, и ничего не понимает в колбасных обрезках. Кроме него на сайт заходить никто не будет. Длинные непонятные ссылки, которые нормально не переслать (как писал @Shamanis). 

Собственно я бы отказался от такого.

Answer (score 3):

Используй фреймворк CodeIgniter.
Для него есть простое решение:
[Русский язык в URL](http://code-igniter.ru/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%B2_URL)

Answer (score 2):

[Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) — очень лёгкий микрофреймворк. Чтобы обрабатывать русскоязычные папки придётся добавить `urlencode()`. Например, для сравнения, `сайт.рф/hello/world` и `сайт.рф/привет/мир`:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get( '/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->get( '/'.urlencode('привет').'/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Preved, $name";
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: а есть ли в этом фреймворке то что я очень ценю в CI:
1) Form Validation
2) File Upload
3) XSS & CRSF
4) Template Parser
5) MVC
6) Active Record
7) Session
8) Image Manipulation
и т.д.?
Конечно может быть ему это всё не надо, если его попросят расширить функционал сайта, то придётся писать на чистом php все эти библиотеки?
Может сразу взять отличный фреймворк, который весит меньше 1 мб?!

Comment: А икс-три, я только только его начал смотреть для маленького API. Сессии - да. Остальное в рамках php, ручками, скорее всего. Среди толстых фреймворков есть и другие достойные. Холиворить нет смысла.

Comment: Silex внешне похож на Slim, в нем этот список присутствует. Ну или Symfony2, или Yii.

Answer (score 0):

мда... не было печали, завели домены на кириллице...
Это да, нормальный выход -  mod_rewrite